# Does such a series of progresses about ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm looking for a way，via which the ideal gas:
 ΔU=0 Q=0 W=0
Does it exists?
Tip:we expect that the gas return to original state

Answer (score 1):

> Does it exists?

Yes. For an isolated system of an ideal gas . An isolated system can't exchange heat ($Q$) nor work ($W$) with its surroundings, nor can gas (mass) flow into or out of the system.

An example is a closed vessel with rigid perfectly insulated walls. No heat transfer, $Q$, is possible ($Q$=0) and no boundary work, $W$, (expansion or contraction of the vessel walls) is possible ($W=0$). Therefore, from the first law

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

$$\Delta U=0$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And apologize for my misunderstanded question.